# What does "reconductor" or "reconductoring" refer to?

Tags: transmission-line, power-engineering, electricity, power-generation

This is a term that I seem to remember hearing in reference to electric transmission. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with upgrading a set of transmission lines to carry more current, but I'm not totally sure. Am I correct here? Can someone please give a thorough explanation of what reconductoring is?

Comment: Are you interested in what the word `reconductor` means (answer given), or, are you interested in cases where and why they would replace the transmission line (i.e. reasons *to* reconductor).

Comment: I'm interested in cases where this term would be used. So yes, pretty much examples.

Answer (score 5):

`reconductor` is a verb.

`to reconductor` means  `to replace conductors`

Comment: i wonder if the usage can be applied to an orchestra ... lol

Comment: I'm sorry, but that doesn't answer my question. I'm wondering what it specifically refers to when electrical engineers or technicians use it.

Comment: @Sagierian what makes you think that's not the answer?

Comment: @Sagierian I'm an electrical engineer and this is what it'd mean if I use it.

Comment: Too vague. The answer below is better.

Answer (score 4):

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reconductor#English):

> **reconductor**
>
> *(electronics)* To replace the cable or wire on an electric circuit, typically a high-voltage transmission line, usually to afford a greater electric-current-carrying capability.

TESMEC, an Italian grid infrastructure contractor, provides [this description of reconductoring](https://www.tesmec.com/en/stringing/applications/reconductoring.html) (emphasis added):

> Power transmission owners and operators need to develop solutions to maintain the transmission efficiency over time or to increase the capacity of existing lines, that are acceptable to the public, reliable and economical. **Reconductoring is the key: renewing the old conductor (line refurbishment) or replacing standard conductors with those of last generation (line improvement).**

So your assumption is correct: Reconductoring is the process of replacing the current-carrying conductors in a transmission line, whether to repair aging lines, increase capacity, or both.

Answer (score 1):

More locally, here is a statement from Long Island PSE&G.

https://www.psegliny.com/reliability/southshoreuniversityhospital

Project specifics:

PSEG Long Island will upgrade the existing area around South Shore University Hospital to address the load growth need in your area. This project includes the installation of underground cable through directional drill and open trenching. **The overhead portion will include re-conductoring wire, equipment upgrades and pole work.** These upgrades will ensure that you and your neighbors receive safe, reliable electric power for years to come.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question--"here's an example of someone using it" isn't really an answer to "what does this mean". And how do you know what counts as local--maybe the asker is Italian!

Comment: Bigger / more wire probably.